# springboot returns different pojos according to different controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, response, dto, pojo

I would like to ask when I have controllerA, I want to display **id, emailTitle, emailBody**, and when controllerB, I want to display **emailBody and correspondingApi**. I would like to ask, is it possible to achieve this assuming there is only one pojo or dto?

```
@Data
public class EmailTemplateDto {

    private Long id;

    private String emailTitle;

    private String emailBody;

    private String correspondingApi;
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/email/template")
public class MailController {

    @Autowired
    private IEmailTemplateService emailTemplateService;
    
    //ControllerA
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllEmailTemplates() {
        return emailTemplateService.getAllEmailTemplates();
    }
    
    //ControllerB
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getEmailTemplateById(@PathVariable Long id) {
      
}  return emailTemplateService.getEmailTemplateById(id);
    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by request? Can you put the code?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being clear enough, I re-edited

Comment: Can you post your service as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use the same DTO for Get requests. It's just going to be serialized into a JSON object, which you can then map from the response on your front end.

You can mostly do the same for other request types, as long as it has all of the fields you need.

That being said, it may be better to define a separate DTO for each situation because you generally don't want to send any more or any less data than what is needed. Just my two cents.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it seems that it is better to divide into two DTO